# Firemonkey TEdit stop editing

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe4

I am creating a temporary TEdit when a button is clicked.  When the button is clicked again I want to do stuff with the text of the TEdit and then remove the TEdit.  My problem is I cannot remove the TEdit while it is still in edit mode.

How can I get the TEdit to disable the focus so that I can destroy it?

Comment: Why are you creating and destroying? Surely easier to show and hide?

Comment: I guess that is what I will need to do.  I just thought it would be best practice to create, use and then destroy as I will not be using this editbox very often and do not want to use memory for no reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you insist on destroying the TEdit, simple set the focus somewhere else:

```
SomeOtherControl.SetFocus;
FreeAndNil(MyEdit);
```

It does seem rather wasteful to create and destroy the TEdit all the time, so you might consider just hiding it:

```
SomeOtherControl.SetFocus;
MyEdit.Visible:= false;
```

Comment: SetFocus does for some reason not take the edit mode off the TEdit. At the moment I am just going to hide it.

Comment: Perhaps the control that you're transfering the focus to is not focusable, because it does not allow input?